# How do I "copy image address" in iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, web-browsing

On desktops, when web browsing you typically right click on an image and choose an item from a contextual menu to display/copy the image URL. In iOS, when you tap and hold down an image, an action sheet displays asking if you want to save the image, copy to the clipboard, etc. But what if you just want the URL?

If safari doesn't offer this functionality, is there a 3rd party browser that does? Specifically, one that works on the iPad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tap, and hold the image; then choose "copy," open a new browser window, and paste into the address bar.

Comment: Very creative, love it! (and updated which is the accepted answer). I wonder if this method worked in iOS 4.x? (when I asked the Q and when rsanchezsaez answered it).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when the image has been set up as a hyperlink to a different URL (i.e. not to the image)...

Comment: I think this stopped working since iOS 15. You copy the whole image now, not the link. There is no paste option (any more?) in the safari tab.

Answer (score 2):

Neither iOS Safari nor Opera Mini support this option. However, you can install the 'view source' iOS bookmarklet, as explained here:

- http://fettig.net/weblog/2007/07/02/view-source-for-safari-on-iphone/

And use it to look for the image link within the source you are visiting.

This may be cumbersome using older iOS versions, but it is much easier on iOS 4.2, using the 'Find text on webpages' feature which allows you to search for text using Safari's Search field (right of the navigation bar) to look for image extensons like .jpg, .png and .gif.

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold, and the 2nd option will be to open it in a new page.  Tap that, and you'll get a new window.  Tap the URL bar, and Copy.

Comment: Nope. Try it with my avatar in this post, it opens my profile b/c the image is inside of a link.

Answer (score 0):

**[Note: this has only been tested on iOS 5.1.1 on iPad]**

For a simple image, you can tap-and-hold it and select 'Copy'. This will copy the URL of the image which you can paste wherever you need it.

However, when the image is being used as a link to another URL, this method copies the linked URL only.

A method that always works is to use the Show Images Bookmarklet ([from here](http://static.chrisbray.com/bookmarklets/) - a useful resource any time you want a bookmarklet on iOS).